# How to code sign a Carthage framework for App Store submission?

Tags: ios, app-store, code-signing, carthage

I have 2 apps I will be submitting to the App Store that work together. Because of this, I have multiple frameworks that both apps use. I use Carthage to package these up.

When I try to submit to the App Store with an Archived build, I get an error on my own framework `Code signing "Authentication.framework" failed.`. `Authentication.framework` is a framework in 3 other frameworks that my app imports.

[image]

When I look at the logs I see that in the step `IDEDistributionCodesignStep`, the 3rd party framework `KeychainAccess` is correctly signed: `Running /usr/bin/codesign <A bunch of parameters here>` then `signed bundle with Mach-O universal (armv7 arm64) [com.kishikawakatsumi.KeychainAccess]`

But when `Authentication.framework`'s turn comes around, the command `Running /usr/bin/codesign <A bunch of parameters here>` results in

`replacing existing signature` then `code object is not signed at all` and `/usr/bin/codesign exited with 1`.

I saw that `KeychainAccess` does auto code signing.

[image]

So I did the same with the `Authentication.framework`, but I get the same results. I also tried not auto code signing, and manually code signing with no luck.

I use auto code signing with the actual application being submitted.

I do have copy-frameworks in my app as well. I do NOT have nested frameworks listed within each framework.

[image]

and down lower:

[image]

**Things I've tried**

- Unchecking auto code sign
- Checking auto code sign with a team
- Checking auto code sign without a team
- `copy-frameworks` Run Script (I have a feeling I'm doing something wrong here, that's why I added the screenshots in case someone catches something I'm doing wrong)

Thanks for the help!

**---------------------- Auto Checked No Team ----------------------**

[image]
[image]
**---------------------- Auto Not Checked ----------------------**
[image]
[image]

Comment: try to uncheck Automatically manage signing for AFramwork(Carthage)

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I have tried that and I got the same error. I've also tried checking the box selecting a team and without selecting a team.

Comment: please check these: 1. Go to Carthage Target -> General -> Singing change according to [picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pbz6B.png) 2. Carthage Target -> Build Settings change according to the [picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z3GVU.png)

Comment: K, I'll try that. This is in the `Authentication.framework` right? (I've updated the question with the actual framework name)

Comment: So you think I need to have it unchecked, but still have the code signing style set to Automatic?

Comment: It looks like `Code Signing Style` is the backing data item for the Xcode UI in `General` so I can't actually do what you're asking because Xcode won't keep it that way.

Comment: You must be checked Automatic singing just for main Target(project)

Comment: Yes, I have automatic signing for the main app/project.

Comment: Ok, unchecked automatic signing for the rest of target and go to build settings and check sign section. one more thing use clean and build again!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/186991/discussion-between-kkendall-and-reza-dehnavi).

Comment: That didn't work for me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had a bunch of issues with my project and nested frameworks. I'll list them here:

- Only the main app that will be submitted to the App Store should have a `Run Script` `copy-frameworks` Phase and it should only copy the top level frameworks.
- Only a test target should have a `Copy Files` Phase (I had a `Copy Files` phase in my framework target)
- Don't embed any frameworks (unless they are static, but those aren't officially supported as of now).
- The frameworks shouldn't be code signed themselves (It should be code signed by the main app)